# MUI Props giving error: `requires between 4 and 5 type arguments`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to wrap a `MuiAutocomplete` around my own custom component and also pass in `AutocompleteProps` as a prop, while using typescript. Here's what I have:

```
type Props = {
  autoCompleteProps?: AutocompleteProps<T>
  label: string
  loading?: boolean
}

const AutoComplete: React.FC<Props> = ({
  autoCompleteProps,
  label,
  loading,
}) => {
  return (
    <MuiAutocomplete {...autoCompleteProps}/>
  )
}
```

But I get the following error on: `autoCompleteProps?: AutocompleteProps<T>`

> Generic type 'AutocompleteProps<T, Multiple, DisableClearable,
> FreeSolo, ChipComponent>' requires between 4 and 5 type arguments

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

And I also want to make `renderInput` optional

Answer (score 3):

`AutocompleteProps` has five generic value and one has default value, others required.

```
export interface CustomAutoCompleteProps<T> {
    autocompleteProps: AutocompleteProps<T, boolean | undefined, boolean | undefined, boolean | undefined>;
    label: string;
    loading?: boolean;
}
```

Component:

```
export const CustomAutoComplete = <T,>(props: CustomAutoCompleteProps<T>) => {
  const { label, autocompleteProps, loading } = props;

  return <Autocomplete {...autocompleteProps} />;
};
```

> And I also want to make renderInput optional

that's not possible, `renderInput` and `options` are required field.

```
interface IOptions {
  label: string;
  year: number;
}

export const AutoCompleteTest = () => {
  let options: CustomAutoCompleteProps<IOptions> = {
    label: "test",
    loading: false,
    autocompleteProps: {
      options: [
        { label: "test", year: 2021 },
        { label: "asd", year: 2222 },
      ],
      renderInput: (params) => <TextField {...params} label={"label"} />,
    },
  };
  return <CustomAutoComplete {...options} />;
};
```

[image: Edit interesting-bash-yicwbc]

Comment: I'm getting many typescript errors and dom errors when i copy and paste this

Comment: I have edited and added sandbox link.

Comment: @Jessica did you check the solution?

Answer (score 1):

As TypeScript says, `AutocompleteProps` needs to have 4 to 5 type arguments as it's defined like the following:

```js
export interface AutocompleteProps<
  T,
  Multiple extends boolean | undefined,
  DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined,
  FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined,
  ChipComponent extends React.ElementType = ChipTypeMap['defaultComponent'],
> {
  // ..
}
```

`ChipComponent` has a default value that's why this props require 5 **or** 4 arguments.

For the others you will need to specify which type to use.

So what you can do is add some generics value to `Props` and simply pass them to the `AutocompleteProps` one:

```js
type Props<
  T,
  Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
  DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
  FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined
> = {
  autoCompleteProps?: AutocompleteProps<
    T,
    Multiple,
    DisableClearable,
    FreeSolo
  >;
  label: string;
  loading?: boolean;
};
```

If you don't care about them in your custom API you can use simple default values:

```js
type Props<T> = {
  autoCompleteProps?: AutocompleteProps<T, undefined, undefined, undefined>;
  label: string;
  loading?: boolean;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you show an example of using it? I'm having trouble getting the return statement working

Comment: Not sure how `MuiAutocomplete` is supposed to work but the types are here valid which was the goal of the question. If you have trouble with the rendering of the component, I will suggest you to open a new question.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this part: `const AutoComplete: React.FC<Props> = ({
  autoCompleteProps,
  label,
  loading,
}) => {
  return (
    <MuiAutocomplete {...autoCompleteProps}/>
  )
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Autocomplete, AutocompleteProps, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

export interface WrappedAutoCompleteProps<
    T,
    Multiple extends boolean | undefined,
    DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined,
    FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
> extends Omit<AutocompleteProps<T | string, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>, 'renderInput'> {
    renderInput?: AutocompleteProps<T | string, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>['renderInput'];
    label?: ReactNode;
}

export default function WrappedAutoComplete<
    T,
    Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
>({ label, ...props }: WrappedAutoCompleteProps<T, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>) {
    return <Autocomplete renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} />} {...props} />;
}
```

Usage:

```
<WrappedAutoComplete
    label="label here"
    multiple
    freeSolo
    options={[]}
/>
```